# Creation of test scripts using multiple data in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

am new to Selenium Testing Automation Tool. I have installed the selenium IDE on my Firefox browser. I jus want to test a login page with different User.id and the Password in Selenium IDE

So where and how do i mention the set of values for the user.id and the password fields.The formation of test scripts using the multiple test data must be performed..Can anyone kindly help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out 2 ways:

1. Either create n different test scripts for Login with different usname/pwd combination.
2. Store the data in a file.Read the file and identify the row count and apply the loop for same...for login and logout...to test various uname pwd combination.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about using Selenium IDE for this.  You might have some luck implementing something that can read in your test data from a properties file or something.

My experience is limited to C# and Java Selenium bindings, but that is how we handled test execution with multiple data sets in those languages.